# AngualrJS: Create a watcher that would get garbage collected

Tags: angularjs, garbage-collection

Is it possible to create a watcher that is tied to an object such that

1) the watcher's handler function uses the object but does not prevent it from garbage collected; and 
2) if the object is garbage collected, the watcher is also de-registered

The use case is that a component has a collection of internal "helpers" that caches derived data, so they need to `$watch` scope variables of the parent. However, they are not angular components (no individual scopes for them) and they're added/removed dynamically without a way of hooking their life-cycle.

I guess I can `$watch` the collection and process the any removals manually, but this seems extremely cumbersome. A more direct solution is welcomed.

Comment: What scope are you using for the `$watch`? Unless deregistered, a $watch will remain for the life of the scope on which it is invoked even if the object that it watches becomes undefined.

Comment: That's exactly the problem. I currently only have access to the parent component's `$scope`, but I would effecitvely want more specific ones that would get recycled with each "helper"./